# How to catch field reset in item:saving event

Tags: content-editor, pipelines, events

I want to make a `item:saving` pipeline processor that will perform some operations when a item field is reset. I thought this would be simple, but it turned out to be trickier than I thought. Maybe I'm just missing something.

When the `item:saving` processor is triggered, I can get the modified fields by `savingItem.Fields.Where(f => f.IsModified)`. I found that, when resetting a field, the fields `Value` is an empty string, `HasValue` is `true` and `ResetBlank` is `false`.

I expected the opposite (`Value` to be `null`, `HasValue` to be `false` and `ResetBlank` is `true`) during the `item:saving`, but the reset operation is eventually performed properly.

How do I distinguish a field reset from storing an empty string in the `item:saving` pipeline? (This is on Sitecore 9.0.1)

Comment: How are you getting at the `savingItem`?

Comment: I get the `savingItem` from the `EventArgs` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information using reflection mechanism and internal `item.GetChanges(true)` method:

1. Get `ItemChanges` by executing `GetChanges(true)` with reflection
2. Get `FieldChanges` from `ItemChanges`.
3. Get underlying `_field` field from every `FieldChange` with reflection again
4. Check if any of the fields has `ResetBlank` flag set to `true`.

Code:

```
public class IsResetEventHandler
{
    private FieldInfo _fieldFieldInfo;
    private FieldInfo FieldFieldInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _fieldFieldInfo ?? (_fieldFieldInfo = typeof(FieldChange).GetField("_field", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance));
        }
    }

    private MethodInfo _getChangesMethodInfo;
    private MethodInfo GetChangesMethodInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _getChangesMethodInfo ?? (_getChangesMethodInfo = typeof(Item).GetMethod("GetChanges", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance));
        }
    }

    public void OnItemSaving(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var savedItem = (args as SitecoreEventArgs)?.Parameters[0] as Item;

            if (savedItem == null)
                return;

            var changes = (ItemChanges) GetChangesMethodInfo.Invoke(savedItem, new object[] { true} );

            var fieldChanges = changes.FieldChanges.Cast<FieldChange>().ToList();

            var isReset = fieldChanges.Any(fc => ((Field) FieldFieldInfo.GetValue(fc)).ResetBlank);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error while checking if it's reset action", ex, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any method to get the information about the field reset from the `args` passed to `item:saving` pipeline.

There is a "hacky" method you can use - you can use client request form values like:

```
var resetFields = Context.ClientPage.ClientRequest.Form.AllKeys.Where(key => key != null && key.StartsWith("Reset_")).Select(key => ShortID.DecodeID(StringUtil.Mid(key, 6))).ToList();
```

This is pretty much the code which is used by the **Reset Fields** dialog. It gets all the request form keys and filters those starting with `Reset_` prefix. Rest of the key is the ID of the field which is reset.

If you need the ids of the fields, you can use the code above. If you need only an information if the `item:saving` is cause by reset fields command, just check if there is any `Reset_***` key.

Comment: Thanks Marek, but that won't be sufficient in my scenario. Fields may be reset by PowerShell scripts, integration jobs and also by users resetting the final layout field. So I need to perform this operations close to the data engine.

Comment: @mikaelnet I added another answer using different approach. I hope it's what you need.